# Items don't appear at Rangers Safe-house fater updating to patch 1.4.0525

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

After getting a high reputation with NCR, Colonel Hsu gave me the key to the Rangers Safe-house near Black Mountain. I went there but reward items were missing, such as the Rangers Combat Armor and other items that should be displayed in the shelf. Also, the NCR officer in charge of the safe-house not showed up.

Reading on line I found this is a bug, and common solutions were to wait a couple of days (up to four days) and then return to the safe-house. I did it and the NCR soldier was there, but not the items.

I also upgraded recently to patch 1.4.0525 and returned to the safe-house, but the items still don't show on the shelf. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Go some place far away and wait 30 days.  This will reset the house and all the stuff will be in there.

Comment: 30? I could have sworn that cells reset in a shorter amount of days..

Comment: It can, but 30 is the upper limit.